# Google cloud shell not opening on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I am clicking on activate cloud shell and this is the problem I am facing this: **Cloud Shell is experiencing some issues provisioning a VM to you. Please try again in a few minutes.**

[When I click on Activate Cloud Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYACj.png)
[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1FD.png)

I tried with multiple devices and multiple chrome users. Also tried it in different network with different laptop and tried to run the cloud shell but still gives the same error. This is the second day of the problem. I am trying for last 24 hours.

I am expecting the cloud shell to open so I can continue my work.

Comment: There's not much we can do. That depends totally in GCP